# Fermat-Catalan eighth powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

There are two Fermat-Catalan solutions that have as an eighth power in their addend the numbers, $33^8$ and $44^8$. In Darmon and Granville's [paper](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/12.Granville/pub12.pdf), they show that the generalized Fermat Equation has only a finite number of solutions when $1/p+1/q+1/r<1$ and an infinite number of solutions when $1/p+1/q+1/r>1$.

Now, where does that leave us for the Fermat-Catalan solutions:

$33^8+1549034^2=15613^3$     and

$43^8+96222^3=30042907^2$ ??

In these cases, it would appear that $1/8+1/3+1/2 = 1/8+1/2+1/3 <1$. BUT,

$33^8=1185921^2$, so I could just as easily say that for this equation, $1/2+1/3+1/2>1$, and likewise for the other equation.  When taken as a square, it belongs to a group of infinite solutions. When taken as an eighth power it is taken as part of a finite group of solutions.  Which is it? Where should it be counted? How can you belong to an infinite group and a finite group at the same time, when the identity between the eighth power and the square indicates you are dealing with one unique solution!?

EDIT 1:  The question is sharpened if we consider the result from [Bennet-Chen](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~ichen/pub/BeCh2.pdf) that the signature $(2,6,n)$ has no solutions.

Since $y^6=(y^3)^2$ then is there a solution or not?  Bennet-Chen proved there is no solution, but $(2,2,n)$ has an infinite number of solutions.  One can only reconcile the two results if circles $(x,y^3,z^{(n/2)})$ don't exist in the infinite family of $(2,2,n)$ for pairwise coprime $x,y,z$ and integer $n$.

Comment: There is no contradiction. The statement says that $x^p+y^q=z^r$ has only finitely many coprime solutions for $1/p+1/1q+1/r<1$. So the equation $x^8+y^2=z^3$ has only finitely many coprime solutions. It doesn't matter that we also get a solution to $x^2+y^2=z^3$, which has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I agree that there is no contradiction, but please see my edit to the question.

Comment: Again: $x^2+y^6=z^n$ has no solution with coprime $x,y$. It doesn't matter that $x^2+y^2=z^n$ has solutions. We have $y^6=(y^2)^3$, but not every square is also a $6$-th power. You should consider explicit solutions before asking. Take $2^2+2^2=2^3$. How should we get a solution of $x^2+y^6=z^n$ out of it?